# Android studio app doesn't load

Tags: java, android

I made my first android app 'Hello World',
When I run it, everything goes fine, without an single error, but
my emulator doesn't load.
I adding screenshot how it's look.
Maybe someone can explain what I miss?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your emulator is coming up but it is very slow.

Android emulator is very slow without intel haxm. 
Please check if your android image is for haxm.

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) link.